# Sublime Text 2 with MIT Scheme

Tags: scheme, sublimetext2, sublimetext, mit-scheme

Does anyone know how i could use sublime text 2 with scheme. I've heard ST2 and I want to try it out? right now I'm learning scheme. I have the scheme interpreter installed - I can go to the terminal and type in scheme and run code. I can also run the interpreter in emacs, but emacs isn't really fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a little bit late but I'd still like to share my experience...

Now I'm using Sublime Text 2 and using Scheme fine.

First install the package ["Scheme"](https://github.com/egrachev/sublime-scheme) through package control.

Then install the package ["SublimeREPL"](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL) (for Sublime Text 2).

Then you should have a fully functioning Scheme environment in your Sublime! Syntax highlight is good, and use SublimeREPL for a interactive Scheme prompt.

Comment: I only have MIT Scheme (doing SICP) and it works perfectly in Sublime

Comment: I am trying to configure mit-scheme in sublime text 3. I have installed Scheme package and SublimeREPL as you mentioned. But after that what should i do ? Sorry, I am a complete beginner with sublime text. Also, what should be the extension for a scheme file here ?

Comment: @nafizh open command pallete (ctrl+shift p) and type "sublimerepl" then choose scheme 'sublimerepl: scheme' and it will open interactive shell inside sublime. and use this fix for the language syntax:
http://www.itkeyword.com/doc/3236135672524131x143/using-scheme-interpreter-in-sublimerepl-package-in-sublime-text-3

Answer (score 0):

I wish my answer would help you~ 
My solution isn't to use  Mit-Scheme but DrScheme,and the specific process is as following:

1. Download PLT-Scheme and install it (http://download.plt-scheme.org/).
2. Add its installation path to environment variables "Path".
3. Install the package "SublimeREPL"
4. Find the file  "Sublime Text 2\Packages\SublimeREPL\config\Scheme\Main.sublime-menu",
   open with Sublime Text 2.  Find the code:

> ```
> "cmd": {"linux": ["scheme"],
>         "osx": ["scheme"],
>         "windows": ["scheme"]},
> ```

and change it :

> ```
> "cmd": {"linux": ["scheme"],
>         "osx": ["scheme"],
>         "windows": ["scheme"]},
> ```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATb6v.png)

Save.

5. Open Sublime Text 2,`ctrl+shift+p`,and enter `scheme`,press `Enter`

Enjoy it！