# Using Scheme interpreter in SublimeRepl package in sublime text 3

Tags: scheme, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I've been up all night trying to figure out how to use the interpreter for SublimeREPL for Scheme in ST3. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081863/starting-sublimerepl-for-scheme-gives-oserror2-no-such-file-or-directory) that when you download the package for sublimeREPL it doesn't actually include the interpretor. So I tried moving my version of MIT-scheme into

/Users/Myname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Scheme

but when I do: Tools --> SublimeREPL --> Scheme --> Scheme

I get:

### Error loading syntax file "Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax/Scheme.tmLanguage": Unable to open Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax/Scheme.tmLanguage

has anyone had any experience being able to set up the interpretor for scheme in SublimeREPL in sublime text 3? I am using os x 10.9.2

Thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: On what OS are you trying to make this work?  Judging by the paths you indicated, it's not Windows, but whether it is MacOS X or Linux may be important.

Comment: @J0e3gan Good point! I am using mac os x 10.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. Though I am using Sublime Text 2, my solution might be applicable to you.

The error message refers to **the wrong path or directory to the Scheme.tmLanguage file**. 
In my case, this file is placed at "Packages/Scheme" here, not at the "Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax" folder. I just **edit Main.sublime-menu** file, change the "syntax": "Packages/sublime-scheme-syntax/Scheme.tmLanguage" line to the correct path and it works!

I found my solution reading [this post](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/249) at SublimeREPL Github site. Hopefully this also works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem and this is how I fix for Sublime Text 2:

1. install the package "Scheme" through package control.
2. install the package "SublimeREPL"
3. install a SCM implementation of Scheme
4. open Preferences -> Browse Packages ->
   SublimeREPL -> config -> Scheme -> Main.sublime-menu. edit the
   section with the "id": "repl_scheme"

args:

```
"windows": ["scm", "-f", "$file_basename"]},
"syntax": "Packages/Scheme/Scheme.tmLanguage"
```

Thanks to: [Sublime Text 2 with MIT Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221293/sublime-text-2-with-mit-scheme), [How to configure SublimeREPL for mit-scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496963/how-to-configure-sublimerepl-for-mit-scheme/22192167#22192167) and @Yenkaku's answer